# Convert legacy HttpWebRequest POST to HttpClient async POST class (VB)

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I have a .net (4.7.2 or 4.8) console app that uses an HttpWebRequest to POST JWT style authentication data in order to retrieve JSON output.  I'm running into issues with TLS 1.2 sites on a Windows Server 2012 box (works fine on Windows 10), and I've been advised to upgrade to the HttpClient async class.  I am struggling to find HttpClient POST examples that use VB.... short of converting the code to C#, what would an HttpClient async POST look like in place of the HttpWebRequest?  The GetAccessToken method is where the issue with HttpWebRequest lies.

Any assistance appreciated!

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Module Module1

    Public Class myAPIClass

        'API info
        Private API_ClientKey As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("API_ClientKey")
        Private API_ClientSecret As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("API_ClientSecret")
        Private FullURL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("URL")
        'Quotation Mark Character for substitution
        Private q As Char = Chr(34)
        'JWT Claim Set Parameters
        Property iss As String = API_ClientKey
        Property aud As String = FullURL
        Property AccessToken As String

        Public Sub New()
            GetAccessToken()
        End Sub

        Public Sub GetAccessToken()
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            Dim uriAddress As New Uri(FullURL)
            Dim wRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(uriAddress), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim strPostData As String = ""
            Dim bytPostData As Byte()
            Dim stJWT As String
            'Get JWT
            stJWT = CreateJWT()
            'Post Data ---
            strPostData = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer" & "&assertion=" & stJWT
            'Post Data --- to byte()
            bytPostData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPostData)
            'Set Web Request Properties
            With wRequest
                .Method = "POST"
                .ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                .ContentLength = bytPostData.Length
            End With

            'Post Request and Get Response
            Using postStream As Stream = wRequest.GetRequestStream()
                postStream.Write(bytPostData, 0, bytPostData.Length)
                Dim rawResponseFromServer = ""
                Try
                    Using response As HttpWebResponse = wRequest.GetResponse()
                        Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                        rawResponseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()
                        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawResponseFromServer)
                        Me.AccessToken = o.Item("access_token").Value(Of String)()
                    End Using

                Catch wex As WebException
                    If Not wex.Response Is Nothing Then
                        Console.WriteLine(wex.Message)
                        Console.WriteLine("Resulting Error --- " & wex.Message & vbNewLine & wex.StackTrace)
                    End If
                End Try
            End Using
        End Sub

#Region "HelperFunctions"
        Private Function CreateJWT() As String
            Dim JWT As String
            Dim EncodedJWT As Byte()

            'Build Header and Claim Set String
            Dim strHeader As String = Strings.Replace("{'alg':'HS256','typ':'JWT'}", "'", q)
            Dim strClaimSet As String = Strings.Replace("{'iss':'" & iss & "', 'aud':'" & aud & "', 'exp':" & exp(600) & ", 'iat':" & iat() & "}", "'", q)

            'Build JWT String
            JWT = ToBase64URL(strHeader) & "." & ToBase64URL(strClaimSet)

            'Convert Client Secret to UTF8 Byte()
            Dim bytKey As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(API_ClientSecret)

            'Encode JWT String
            Dim hmac_encode As HMACSHA256 = New HMACSHA256(bytKey)
            EncodedJWT = hmac_encode.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JWT))

            'Sign and return JWT
            Dim signature As String = ToBase64URL(EncodedJWT)
            Return JWT & "." & signature
        End Function

        Private Function ToBase64URL(Text As String) As String

            Dim b As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text)
            Return ToBase64URL(b)

        End Function

        Private Function ToBase64URL(byt As Byte()) As String

            Dim result As String
            'Convert to base 64 string
            result = Convert.ToBase64String(byt)
            'Make URL Friendly
            result = result.Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_")
            Do While result.Chars(result.Length - 1) = "="
                result = Strings.Left(result, result.Length - 1)
            Loop
            Return result

        End Function

        ReadOnly Property exp(ExpirationSeconds As Integer) As Long
            Get
                Return iat() + ExpirationSeconds
            End Get
        End Property

        ReadOnly Property iat() AsLong
        Get
                Dim StartDate As Date = CDate("1/1/1970")
                Dim EndDate As Date = Now.ToUniversalTime
                Dim val As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, StartDate, EndDate)
                Return val
            End Get

        End Property

#End Region

    End Class
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Getting token...")
        Dim myif As New myAPIClass()

        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Token received:  " & myif.AccessToken)
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to SQL Server and inserting authentication token...")
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MYDB (InsertDate, AuthenticationCode, Length) VALUES ('" & DateTime.Now.ToString() & "', '" & myif.AccessToken & "', 40)", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Console.WriteLine("Done!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Console.WriteLine("Resulting Error --- " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GetAccessToken method should look like this :

```
Public Sub GetAccessToken()

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    Dim tokenHttpClient As New HttpClient()
    tokenHttpClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(FullURL)

    Dim HttpRequestMessage As New HttpRequestMessage()
    HttpRequestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Post
    HttpRequestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

    Dim stJWT As String = CreateJWT()

    Dim parameters As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    parameters.Add("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer")
    parameters.Add("assertion", stJWT)

    Dim encodedContent As New FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters)
    encodedContent.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    HttpRequestMessage.Content = encodedContent

    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = tokenHttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage).Result

    If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        Dim rawResponseFromServer As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawResponseFromServer)
        Me.AccessToken = o.Item("access_token").Value(Of String)()
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that all functions used in httpClient are async, the .Result force it in a syncronous way instead of having to await them

I'm not sure that it will solve your tls issue. You will perhaps need to add an httpClientHandler

```
Dim httpClientHandler As New HttpClientHandler()
httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 Or Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = AddressOf TrustAllCertificatesCallback

tokenHttpClient = New HttpClient(httpClientHandler)    

Private Function TrustAllCertificatesCallback(sender As Object, certificate As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

Property HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols is available in Assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0